# Two sprite-drawing functions for Amara game

Tags: javascript, game, animation, canvas

Ideally I would have one draw method in the parent class (`Player`).

But I can't figure out how to do this. I don't know if there is anyway to decouple it totally. I don't mind modifying the sprite sheet so that it can handle this sort of thing.

Any tips are very welcome!!

Both classes inherit from `Player`.

```
var skeleton =  Player(x, y, hp, name, moveSpeed);
//drawing the fly

var draw = function(ctx) {

if (flyAnimate >= 30){
  flyAnimate = 0;
}
var bugX = canvas.width/2 + fly.getDrawAtX() - localX - 50;

if (fly.getAlive()){
  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(bugX+30,fly.getDrawAtY()-50,((fly.getHp()/2.2)),6);
} else {
  ctx.fillText("DEAD", bugX + 37, fly.getDrawAtY()-40);
}

if (flyAnimate <= 10){
  ctx.drawImage(flySprite,0,0, 100, 100, bugX,fly.getDrawAtY()-50, 100, 100);
}

else if (flyAnimate <= 20){
  ctx.drawImage(flySprite,100,0, 100, 100, bugX,fly.getDrawAtY()-50, 100, 100);
}
else if (flyAnimate <= 30){
  ctx.drawImage(flySprite,200,0, 100, 100, bugX,fly.getDrawAtY()-50, 100, 100);
}
ctx.drawImage(silverShield, bugX+ 20, fly.getDrawAtY()-3);

if (descendAttack || rightMouseActionHappening){
  if (!rightMouseActionHappening){
    rightMouseActionHappening = true;
  }
  //200 is pretty badass
}

if (descendAttack) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(bugX+60, fly.getDrawAtY()-40 + 90);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
  ctx.drawImage(silverSword, 0, -10);
  ctx.restore();
} else {
  ctx.drawImage(silverSword, bugX+ 60, fly.getDrawAtY()-40);
}
flyAnimate++;

ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.font = "bold 13px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText(name, bugX + 22, fly.getDrawAtY()-60);
};
```

// drawing what I call a redhatter

```
var draw = function(ctx) {
//var drawAtX = skeleton.getX()-50;
if (skeleton.getMoveDirection() === "left"){
  facing_left = true;
} else if (skeleton.getMoveDirection() === "right"){
  facing_left = false;
}
if (facing_left){
  spritesheet_offset_y = 102;
}
else {
  spritesheet_offset_y = 0;
}
var   drawAtX = canvas.width/2 + skeleton.getDrawAtX() - localX - 50;

if (skeleton.getAlive()){
  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(drawAtX+30,skeleton.getY()-50,((skeleton.getHp()/2.2)),6);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
} else { /* If it's dead, just write DEAD */
  ctx.fillText("DEAD", drawAtX + 37, skeleton.getY()-40);
}
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.font = "bold 13px sans-serif";
ctx.fillText(name, drawAtX + 25, skeleton.getY()-60);

/* Decides what sprite to draw*/
if (skeleton.getAnimate() <= 20){
  ctx.drawImage(RedhatterSprite,0,spritesheet_offset_y, 100, 100, drawAtX,skeleton.getY()-50, 100, 100);
}
else if (skeleton.getAnimate() <= 40){
  ctx.drawImage(RedhatterSprite,100,spritesheet_offset_y, 100, 100, drawAtX,skeleton.getY()-50, 100, 100);
}
else if (skeleton.getAnimate() <= 60){
  ctx.drawImage(RedhatterSprite,200,spritesheet_offset_y, 100, 100, drawAtX,skeleton.getY()-50, 100, 100);
} else{
  ctx.drawImage(RedhatterSprite,200,spritesheet_offset_y, 100, 100, drawAtX,skeleton.getY()-50, 100, 100);
}
};
```

Here is the [full source on GitHub](https://github.com/hassanshaikley/amara-game/tree/99e9eda2d83fd8fa3d31fc54fb97dae01b3c4249).

Answer (score 3):

I stopped reading through the code when I got to this:

> ```
> if (descendAttack || rightMouseActionHappening){
>   if (!rightMouseActionHappening){
>     rightMouseActionHappening = true;
>   }
>   //200 is pretty badass
> }
> ```

First, that comment means nothing to the code, get rid of it.

Second thing is that the inside operation will never get called when `rightMouseActionHappening` is true,  I am not sure how this is supposed to work, if you try something like

```
if (true) {
    if (false){
        console.log("true");
    }
}
```

you won't get an answer from it, so what I mean is that you should write this a little more like this

```
if (descendAttack && !rightMouseActionHappening){
    rightMouseActionHappening = true;
}
```

because the inner if isn't going to be called if `rightMouseActionHappening` is true, so don't test for that.

once we have gone this far, if `rightMouseActionHappening` is true, reassigning it to true isn't going to hurt it at all, so we might as well drop it off.

```
if (descendAttack){
    rightMouseActionHappening = true;
}
```

Now, the next statement is another if checking `descendAttack` again, so we might just want to merge these together like this

```
if (descendAttack) {
  rightMouseActionHappening = true;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(bugX+60, fly.getDrawAtY()-40 + 90);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
  ctx.drawImage(silverSword, 0, -10);
  ctx.restore();
} else {
  ctx.drawImage(silverSword, bugX+ 60, fly.getDrawAtY()-40);
}
```

---

all of your code could use another indentation inside of the functions, so that I know that it is inside of a function.

---

> ```
> if (skeleton.getMoveDirection() === "left"){
>   facing_left = true;
> } else if (skeleton.getMoveDirection() === "right"){
>   facing_left = false;
> }
> ```

I would change this into a simple assignment like this

```
facing_left = skeleton.getMoveDirection() === "left"
```

and this

> ```
> if (facing_left){
>   spritesheet_offset_y = 102;
> } else {
>   spritesheet_offset_y = 0;
> }
> ```

I would change into a ternary assignment statement like this

```
spritesheet_offset_y = facing_left ? 102 : 0;
```

Comment: Thank you! This question is ancient and I have rewritten this code. If it makes you feel any better a lot of this has already been sorted out!

Comment: You should post what we call a selfie, and show how you sorted everything out. I would love to see the code and read the review.